# Issue while retrieving varchar values from Stored procedure in Mule

Tags: stored-procedures, mule

Hi I'm not able to retrieve the varchar values from Stored procedure in to my mule flow. It is always returning NULL values.I have followed the same order while declare the output parameters both in mule and in stored procedure script. Here is my mule flow and a sample stored procedure script i'm using.Please help to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

```js
   <db:oracle-config name="Oracle_Configuration" host="localhost" port="1521" instance="xe" user="user1" password="user1" doc:name="Oracle Configuration"/>
    <flow name="SPTestFlow">
        <poll doc:name="Poll">
            <fixed-frequency-scheduler frequency="1000" timeUnit="DAYS"/>
            <logger message="Started" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        </poll>
        <db:stored-procedure config-ref="Oracle_Configuration" doc:name="CostCalculationSP" >
            <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[call user1.CARRINV(:MSG,:CD)]]></db:parameterized-query>
            <db:out-param name="MSG" type="VARCHAR"/>
            <db:out-param name="CD" type="VARCHAR"/>
        </db:stored-procedure>
        <logger message="#[payload[MSG]],#[payload[CD]]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>
```

Sample Stored Procedure script

```css
create or replace PROCEDURE CARRINV 
(
 MSG OUT VARCHAR2,
 CD OUT VARCHAR2
) AS 
BEGIN

  MSG:='success';
  CD:='1';
exception
WHEN OTHERS THEN
MSG:= SQLERRM;
CD:= '0';
END CARRINV;
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be your syntax in the logger (Note the quotes around the parameters) -  Try this :

```
<logger message="#[payload['MSG']],#[payload['CD']]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

Also please try putting braces around the db call:

```
<db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[{call user1.CARRINV(:MSG,:CD)}]]></db:parameterized-query>
```

Adding reference : http://bushorn.com/mule-with-stored-procedure/

Comment: i have run this code in debug mode and could see the Null values well before the logger in debugger.

Comment: Could you post what you see when you run your stored proc in oracle?

Comment: Hi Jvas, my flow is correct the issue is with my oracle driver, after importing new driver i was able to fetch the values . Thanks

Comment: What new driver was that, and what was your old driver? Thanks!